# How to get the value of checkboxes in the order they are selected on a jsp page?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2

I am having four checkboxes in a jsp page. I want to get their values in the order they are selected. Suppose checkboxes are having values A, B, C, D. If I select first B, then D, then A and finally C. I should get B,D,A,C. These values I need to send to java.

Comment: Keep in mind that, after you do this, your user will have no way to know the order; i.e., you are transgressing a basic user interface principle that the user be able to look at his own input.  If this is really important and the user is supposed to be able to tell, then you should consider using a different control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot to you all. Finally I got the result using suggestions from you all.
I used : 
**JavaScript Code** :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    arr = new Array();

    function updatePriority(elemId){

      var elem = document.getElementById("foo");
      var chkBox = document.getElementById(elemId);
      var options = document.getElementsByName('checkbox1');

       if(document.getElementById(elemId).checked) {    
   alert("checked");         
 arr.push(elemId);  
     }
       else { 
          for(var i = arr.length; i>=0; i--){
      if(arr[i]==elemId){
        arr.splice(i,1);
         break;
               }
      }
            }

      for(var i = (arr.length-1); i>=0; i--){
       alert("checked value list ::"+arr[i]);

      }


   }
```

I am getting output in the reverse order. That is not a problem as I can easily handle this from Java side.

Answer (score 1):

HTML has no control that allows you to order values. You would have to use JavaScript to track what order things were clicked in (or have a form submission per selection).

The simplest approach to this would be to have a hidden input to which you `hidden.value += this.value` with a click event on the checkboxes.

You would need to decide on your business logic for what happens if a checkbox is deselected and implement that too.

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
$('#isAgeSelected').attr('checked')
```

this will return true or fasle

Answer (score 1):

May not be the best way, but could be done by a roundabout approach by updating an hidden input field constantly using the onClick attribute of the Radio buttons. 
Untested code:

```
<script>
 function updateFoo(elemId){
   var elem = document.getElementById("foo");
   elem.value = elem.value+", "+elemId;
   console.log(elem.value);        
}

funcition cleanFoo(){
   //Now clean the string to remove the ',' at the beggining and the end and to 
   //contain A,B,C,D only once
   /*
    Scan the string from the back and keep the last occurence of each ID
    since the user can select or click on radio buttons more than once
    Eg. a,b,c,d,b,b,c,a,d,d,a
    Keep:         b,c,    d,a  //final selections
    //I may write a code here when I get some time
    */
}

</script>
<body>
<input type="radio" id="A" onClick="updateFoo('A')">A<br/>
<input type="radio" id="B" onClick="updateFoo('B')">B<br/>
<input type="radio" id="C" onClick="updateFoo('C')">C<br/>
<input type="radio" id="D" onClick="updateFoo('D')">D<br/>
<input type="hidden" id="foo" value="">
</body>
```

Comment: I saw that a few answers have already mentioned this approach. I can delete this answer or I guess will still keep this one as it has some skeleton code.

Answer (score 0):

1)Add a new hidden input field.
2)Populate the value according to user selection
3)Read the hidden varible at server.

eg:initially hidden_variable=""

When user selects B ,hidden_variable="B"
When user selects C ,hidden_variable="B,C" like this.

If the user unselects a value, remove that value from hidden_variable.

All this you can do with some basic js functionalities

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a `<input type="hidden" id="myList"/>` to send the value to Java.

When the checkboxes are checked / unchecked, you call a javascript function that append (or remove, with using of `substring` and `indexOf`) the value of the checkbox to the hidden field.

EDIT: AND this is a duplicate: [Detect order in which checkboxes are clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846712/detect-order-in-which-checkboxes-are-clicked)